# Incorrect text displayed in calculator app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the label to display the numbers and operator (plus or minus or whatever) and next number before the user taps the equal sign for the result.  What I get is the first number, then when the operator is tapped (only been testing with plus), the first number is erased from the screen and replaced by the operator symbol plus the second number when tapped.

Can someone help show me what I'm doing wrong? It's my first Swift project ever.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLbl: UILabel!

    var runningNumber = ""
    var leftValue = ""
    var rightValue = ""
    var result = ""
    var currentOperation:Operation = .NULL

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        outputLbl.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        if runningNumber.count <= 8 {
            runningNumber += "\(sender.tag)"
            outputLbl.text = runningNumber
        }
    }

    @IBAction func allClearPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        runningNumber = ""
        leftValue = ""
        rightValue = ""
        result = ""
        currentOperation = .NULL
        outputLbl.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func dotPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        if runningNumber.contains(".") {
        } else {
            runningNumber += "."
            outputLbl.text = runningNumber
        }
    }

    @IBAction func equalPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        operation(operation: currentOperation)
    }

    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        operation(operation: .Add)
        runningNumber += "\("+")"
        outputLbl.text = runningNumber
    }

    @IBAction func subtractPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        operation(operation: .Subtract)
    }

    @IBAction func multiplyPressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        operation(operation: .Multiply)
    }

    @IBAction func dividePressed(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        operation(operation: .Divide)
    }

    func operation (operation:Operation){
        if currentOperation != .NULL{
            if runningNumber != ""{
                rightValue = runningNumber
                runningNumber = ""

                if currentOperation == .Add{
                    result = "\(Double(leftValue)! + Double(rightValue)!)"
                } else if currentOperation == .Subtract{
                    result = "\(Double(leftValue)! - Double(rightValue)!)"
                } else if currentOperation == .Multiply{
                    result = "\(Double(leftValue)! * Double(rightValue)!)"
                } else if currentOperation == .Divide{
                    result = "\(Double(leftValue)! / Double(rightValue)!)"
                }
                leftValue = result
                if (Double(result)!.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0){
                    result = "\(Int(Double(result)!))"
                }
                outputLbl.text = result
            }
            currentOperation = operation

        } else {
            leftValue = runningNumber
            runningNumber = ""
            currentOperation = operation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `func addPressed`, the first function `operation(operation: .Add)` is setting your `runningNumber` to an empty String value `""`. After, the `runningNumber += "\("+")"` is called what gives you `"" + "\("+")"`, that's why your label is showing you the operator. It means that the logic is a bit broken. You should not reset your `runningNumber` value, or probably add some kind of variable that will hold your output String value.

Also, I would recommend you to optimize your code and rather use the switch-case in your `func operation(operation: Operation)` instead of multiple if-else statements. Would help you to improve code readability.

Comment: bu then why does it work with the dotPressed function?

Comment: Cause when you're calling the `func dotPressed`, you're checking if there is `"."` and if not, you're adding the dot to the current `runningNumber` value. In this case `runningNumber` is not set to an empty String like it is in the `func operation` function where you're using `runningNumber = ""`. `+=` means add the current value of this variable to the following value and set the result to this variable (`runningNumber += "8"` will be `runningNumber = runningNumber + "8"`). But when you're using just equals operator `=` you're just setting the new value (`runningNumber = ""` will be `""`)

Comment: ok so I added a variable outputString and I've added it to the number pressed function as 'code'outputString = runningNumber, and added it to the operator functions as outputString += "+", then outputLbl.text = outputString. that works.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to carry outputString forward to add what will be the rightValue in the expressions.  So far I've tried adding outputString += rightValue, and outputLbl.text = outputString to the operation function just before runningNumber = "".  No luck.  Do I need another variable or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Got it!  I added 'outputString = runningNumber' after 'leftValue = runningNumber' and before 'runningNumber = ""', then 'outputString += runningNumber' in my numberPressed function and changed the 'outputLbl.text = outputString'.  thanks livenplay!